# How to save latitude and longitude (location) in Shared Preference

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I want to get the longitude and latitude co-ordinates of a location and save in a ArrayList, then commit this list to SharedPreference file so when the Map loads all previous locations could be set with a marker using data from the SharedPreference file.

I only know realise that SharedPreference will only store primitive data types and not arrays.

My question does is anybody know of a way to persist this data  either via shared pref technique or by any alternate means?

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- create a class and put everything you want to store for example `arraylist` of your `latitude` and `longitude` and make that class implement `Serializable` interface.

```
class MyBundle  implements Serializable {

   ArrayList<Double> mLat;
   ArrayList<Double> mLan;

   MyBundle( ArrayList<Double> latitude, ArrayList<Double> longitude ){

    mLat = latitude;
    mLan = longitude;

   }

}
```

2- write it to file:

```
 ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
 FileOutputStream fout = null;
 try{
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("Your file path");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(mb); // mb is an instance of MyBundle
 } catch (Exception ex) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }finally {
   if(oos  != null){
     oos.close();
   } 
 }
```

and to get back everything:

```
 ObjectInputStream objectinputstream = null;
 try {
        streamIn = new FileInputStream("Your file address");
        objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(streamIn);
        MyBundle mb = (MyBundle) objectinputstream.readObject();

   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }finally {
     if(objectinputstream != null){
        objectinputstream .close();
     } 
   }
```

Comment: So I could create inner class implementing serializable, store /retrive long/lat doubles using setters/getters and writing to/getting back from file. What should the file path be? Does this have to be ant particular directory?

Comment: first inner class must also implement `serializable` and second file path could be anything your external storage or internal for example it can be your internal cache `Activity.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath().toString()`

Comment: Will this work if writing a new object to file each time user selects a new location in between activities/app launches or will objects simply be overwritten in file?

Comment: it depends on how you write it if you overwrite that you lost previous data if you append that it is not. i do not understand exactly what you want to do may be you need database, because i think you want to store all of user locations from first lunch of your app till now.

Comment: I suppose you could read the object form file, then  add additional coords via an arrayList and save again thereby not overwritten any previous data??.....want to avoid using and  modifying current database schema if possible

Comment: `I suppose you could read the object form file, then add additional coords via an arrayList and save again thereby not overwritten any previous data??` yes you can do that!!

Comment: Actually having some issues implementing the code, namely creating the file to write to....have posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960752/file-not-found-saving-object-to-phone-file-directory

Answer (score 3):

You can store them as Strings separated with a period/comma. But in the case of latitude and longitude, you shouldn't use period because they have period (latitude = 27 **.** 345)

**For example**

```
String aLocation = latitude + "," + longitude//store this to sharedpreference
```

This won't be a problem for longitude and latitude as there is no comma(but has period) that can conflict to your limiter.

And while retrieving the location you can split it and get corresponding longitude and latitude.

```
String[] locationArray = pref.getString(KEY_LOCATION, "").split(","); 
String retrievedLat = locationArray[0];
String retrievedLong = locationArray[1];//you may need to use trim() method
```

Also you can convert this to **JSON** and save it. But I would prefer the above method as it's easier and will not give any problem to your scenario.

But in cases where you need to store Strings with special characters like period, you need to make it JSON because it may **conflict your limiter**

So you can do as following:

```
public void addToPref(LatLng location){//I'm supposing you are using LatLang class
    String aLocation = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
//and save to shared preference
    }
```

**Update:**

If you want to enter multiple number of location then you need use JSON(prefered) but the first approach is easier. **See below**

```
1. Get string from preference
2. Concatenate it with the new location
```

Like:

```
oldLocation,newLocation,newerLocation
```

P.S. You may have longitude and latitude to each location so the string must be like

```
{lat1,long1}:{lat2,lat2}:{lat3,long3}
```

And in this case you need to have multiple limiters and do (split accordingly).

Using **split(":")** method will give you multiple locations.

And further split it using **split(",")** that will give you corresponding latitude and longitude.

Comment: Tried the first approach with Shred prefs but became stuck trying to saved multiple locations as strings in Shared pref as in could not make each String holding a location unique so as each individual location could be called rfm Shared Prefs later . So his does the JSON persist data? Have not used before

Comment: Sorry! But cannot understand what you mean? Please explain.

Comment: I have used the first approach in similar application. It was working perfectly

Comment: Sure, so for every location I convert the lat long co-ords to a String (lat/Long), then split using the '/' delimiter. So how do we make each String location commit to SP's unique so we can get the same String later and not be overwritten by the next location string? Hope that makes sense not very well explained....

Comment: So the problem is, "What if the location duplicates?"

Comment: Well not the location per say but the String holding the location data...ie String Location = StringValue.Of(lat+"/"long); shreadPrefsEditor.putString("theLocation", Location);  When getting the String theLocation=sharedPrefs.getString("theLOcation", ""); thelOcation will be overwriietn with new String every time a location is saved to shared prefs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61620/discussion-between-nabin-and-dancingbush).

Comment: cheers for all your help, I went with the serlized object approach as anticipated issues with memory management for storing the data in Strings with the shared pref method.

Answer (score 1):

well i used these methods using simple functions

```
// Saving GeoFence marker with prefs mng
    private void saveGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveGeofence()");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().latitude ));
        editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().longitude ));
        editor.apply();
    }

    // Recovering last Geofence marker
    private void recoverGeofenceMarker() {
        Log.d(TAG, "recoverGeofenceMarker");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );

        if ( sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT ) && sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON )) {
            double lat = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, -1 ));
            double lon = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, -1 ));
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng( lat, lon );
            markerForGeofence(latLng);
            drawGeofence();
        }
    }
```