# My lastLocation shows null on a few devices and crashes my app

Tags: java, android

My lastLocation show in few devices and cruch my app

Here is my code:
...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private MapView mMapView;
private View mView;
private MarkerOptions marker;
private Location location;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    addMarker();
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    String lat1 = String.valueOf(lat);
    String lng1 = String.valueOf(lng);

    //Define list to get all latLng for the route
    ArrayList<LatLng> path = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    //Execute Directions API request
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
            .apiKey(API_KEY)
            .build();
    DirectionsApiRequest req = DirectionsApi.getDirections(context, lat1 + ", " + lng1, "31.742462, 34.985447");
    try {
        DirectionsResult res = req.await();

        //Loop through legs and steps to get encoded polyLines of each step
        if (res.routes != null && res.routes.length > 0) {
            DirectionsRoute route = res.routes[0];

            if (route.legs != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                    DirectionsLeg leg = route.legs[i];
                    if (leg.steps != null) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < leg.steps.length; j++) {
                            DirectionsStep step = leg.steps[j];
                            if (step.steps != null && step.steps.length > 0) {
                                for (int k = 0; k < step.steps.length; k++) {
                                    DirectionsStep step1 = step.steps[k];
                                    EncodedPolyline points1 = step1.polyline;
                                    if (points1 != null) {
                                        //Decode polyline and add points to list of route coordinates
                                        List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> coords1 = points1.decodePath();
                                        for (com.google.maps.model.LatLng coord1 : coords1) {
                                            path.add(new LatLng(coord1.lat, coord1.lng));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                EncodedPolyline points = step.polyline;
                                if (points != null) {
                                    //Decode polyline and add points to list of route coordinates
                                    List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> coords = points.decodePath();
                                    for (com.google.maps.model.LatLng coord : coords) {
                                        path.add(new LatLng(coord.lat, coord.lng));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    //Draw the polyline
    if (path.size() > 0) {
        PolylineOptions opts = new PolylineOptions().addAll(path).color(Color.BLUE).width(5);
        googleMap.addPolyline(opts);
    }

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(31.742462, 34.985447), 10));
}

public void addMarker() {
    marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(31.742462, 34.985447)).title("בית הכנסת - נווה צדק").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "בית הכנסת - נווה צדק", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My lastLocation show null in few devices and cruch my app*

Comment: If the cellphone is reinited, the lastLocation become null if no know location get to be know, you must wait for a update then

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos how i can do code are fix that or give the app not being null?

Comment: You could save the lastLocation in shared preference and if its null set it to that location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836350/how-to-save-latitude-and-longitude-location-in-shared-preference.

Comment: Extract all logic of what to do after getting a Location then use the locationmanager to ```requestSingleUpdate``` and wait in the listener to get one